# Как избавиться от знака "<", при вставке php-кода в HTML-страницу

Tags: php, html, html5, phpstorm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
появляется знак меньше, подскажите как от него избавиться. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 8):

Первый символ первой строки удалите. Который перед `<!doctype`.